# GRANT VIEW privilege on DEFINITION of PACKAGE

Tags: oracle, sql-grant

Below is for SQL server but what could do the same for Oracle server.

```
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON DCF_PKG_RETRIEVE TO EWPWFL;
```

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what you want to do, for those not familiar with the SQL Server command? Have you tried just looking at the data dictionary, particularly [`all_source`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/statviews_2064.htm)? If that doesn't give you what you need you'll need to be more specific I think.

Comment: I second Alex's comment - something like `select text from all_source where type = 'PACKAGE' and name = 'DCF_PKG_RETRIEVE'` should return the package definition. You may need to grant select on all_source to EWPWFL - but often that privilege is granted to PUBLIC so you may not need that step.